# How to mock a function in Karma.js

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, thymeleaf

Does somebody knows how to mock a function result with karma.js ?
The function uses a var given by thymeleaf framework (java, spring boot, etc..).

```
function isFlooring() {
    var isMyChoiceOk = [[${mychoice}]];
    if(typeof isMyChoiceOk !== 'undefined') {
        return isMyChoiceOk;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to tell karma.js that the result of this function is TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a spy on the function (this assumes your function isn't part of an object) and then replace it with your own function:

```
spyOn(window, 'isFlooring')
    .and.callFake( function(arguments) {
         // return whatever you want to here
         return true
     }
```

The spy just listens for that function to be called and then 'callFake' replaces the functionality with what you want it to be.

If your function is part of an object, replace 'window' in the 'spyOn' call with the name of the object.